# Call method from Master Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, formview, master-pages

i want to call a method that placed in  tag in master page

like this

```
<script runat="server">  
protected void usernameTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
}  
</script>
```

inside a form that uses this master page.

note: that i will use this method for example by a textbox inside formview

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At form load assign the master page textbox handler to your content page Textbox event.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MasterPageClassName MyMasterPage = (MasterPageClassName)Page.Master; 

    TextBox t = new TextBox();
    t.TextChanged += new EventHandler(MyMasterPage.usernameTextBox_TextChanged);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call event handlers like functions, so unless reusing the event handler for another control on the content page, you should create a public method in the master page that does whatever the event handler is doing:

In the master page:

```
protected void usernameTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SomeMethod();
}

public void SomeMethod()
{
    //do your logic in this method
}
```

On the page, add this line to the page directive:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Themes/Master.master" %>
```

After adding that line to the page directive, you can call the method like this:

```
Master.SomeMethod();
```

Comment: How about reusing the handler ?

Answer (score 0):

within your page add this directive along with the page directive as follows:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="A.aspx.cs" Inherits="StackOverflow.A" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site.Master" %>
```

and from some method inside your page, call the method foo() (this is defined in your master page) ( make sure this is public)

```
((SiteMaster)this.Master).foo();
```

my master page's name is SiteMaster

this is how you can call a memeber in your master page. i am not sure if it will work correctly for the method you want to call(most probably if the passed arguments are not good enough)